# Spring JTA Transaction manager question

Tags: spring, jboss, jpa-2.0, jta

We are using jboss managed EntityMangerFactory using following spring bean

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence-units/myPU"/>
```

Now in our spring bean we use @PersistenceContext to get the entitymanager and it works fine. What I want is that how can i tell spring to grab the transaction manager provided by jbos jta service and use it in my dao?

If I define the txmanager like below then can spring will take controll of managing the transction with @Transaction annotation?

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
      <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="UserTransaction"/>
</bean>
```

If so then when spring will commit the transaction and roll back it?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost - you should call it `transactionManager` rather than `txManager`. You can override the name that it looks for, but it's easier to stick to the convention.

Also, `JtaTransactionManager` will generally auto-detect the various JNDI names, you shouldn't need to specify them manually.

Better yet, don't declare `JtaTransactionManager` at all, just use `<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>`, and [Spring should do the right thing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-application-server-integration).

So, all you should need is:

```
<context:annotation-driven/>
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
```

Once that's in place, any beans annotated with `@Transactional` will have their transaction boundaries managed by Spring, e.g. have transactions committed or rolled back when the annotated method exits ([see docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)).

Comment: Thanks skaffman. This is working fine. By the way I didn't understand <tx:jta-transaction manager> configuration. How does spring will find transaction provided by server?

Comment: @user509755: By looking for it at a known list of possible locations.